# Attached property to update style trigger on event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use an attached property to trigger a style change on a `UIElement` when an event has fired.

Here is the case scenario:

A user sees a `TextBox`, and focuses then unfocuses it. Somewhere in an attached property it notices this `LostFocus` event and sets a property (somewhere?) to say that it `HadFocus`.

The style on the TextBox then knows that it should style itself differently based on this HadFocus property.

Here's how I imagine the markup to look...

```
<TextBox Behaviors:UIElementBehaviors.ObserveFocus="True">
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Behaviors:UIElementBehaviors.HadFocus" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

I've tried a few combinations of the attached properties to get this working, my latest attempt throws a `XamlParseException` stating **"Property can not be null on Trigger."**

```
    public class UIElementBehaviors
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObserveFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ObserveFocus",
                                            typeof (bool),
                                            typeof (UIElementBehaviors),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnObserveFocusChanged));
    public static bool GetObserveFocus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(ObserveFocusProperty);
    }
    public static void SetObserveFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ObserveFocusProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnObserveFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as UIElement;
        if (element == null) return;

        element.LostFocus += OnElementLostFocus;
    }
    static void OnElementLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        if (element == null) return;

        SetHadFocus(sender as DependencyObject, true);

        element.LostFocus -= OnElementLostFocus;
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HadFocusPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("HadFocusKey",
                                                    typeof(bool),
                                                    typeof(UIElementBehaviors),
                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HadFocusProperty = HadFocusPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public static bool GetHadFocus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HadFocusProperty);
    }

    private static void SetHadFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HadFocusPropertyKey, value);
    }
}
```

Anyone able to direct me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registering a readonly dependency property does not mean to add `Key` to the property name. Just replace

```
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("HadFocusKey", ...);
```

by

```
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("HadFocus", ...);
```

since `HadFocus` is the name of the property.